# Question on MIT video on Markov matrices

Tags: matrices, markov-process, stochastic-matrices

Markov matrices are pretty new to me and I'm a little rusty with my linear algebra.  My question stems from watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnssRe5DewE) from YouTube on Markov matrices.  For those who wish to skip the video, the following notation was used.  The location of a particle after $n$ steps is $p_n$, $A$ was a Markov matrix for the process and $p_\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n$.

During the video he claims that every Markov matrix has an eigenvalue of $1$, but does not explain why (from a previous lecture perhaps).  More importantly, at the very end, he seems to strongly imply but does come out and say that $p_\infty$ is always a multiple of the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of $1$.  If this should be true, is this because if a limit should exist, we want

$$Ap_\infty=p_\infty\text?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, people deal with a right stochastic matrix i.e. each row contains non-negative real numbers and sum to $1$.

The instructor on the video uses a left stochastic matrix i.e. each column contains non-negative real numbers and sum to $1$.

Following the convention the instructor follows, note that for a $n \times n$ left stochastic matrix, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
since each column sum of $A$ is $1$. Hence, $1$ is a left eigenvalue of $A$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is a left eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ for the left stochastic matrix. Recall that the left and right eigen values of $A$ are same. Hence, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Now at "steady state", we have
$$p_{\infty}(i) = \sum_{j} A(i,j)p_{\infty}(j)$$
Hence, we have
$$Ap_{\infty} = p_{\infty}$$ i.e. $p_{\infty}$ is the right-eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ for the left stochastic matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A stochastic matrix is one where the sum of each row is equal to $1$. A Markov matrix is a stochastic matrix. Now, notice that the vector $v=(1,1,1,\cdots ,1)\in \mathbb R^n$ is an eigenvector of any stochastic $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with eigenvalue $1$ (simply because when you multiply $M\cdot v$ the entry of each entry in the result is the sum of the corresponding row in $M$, which is $1$ by stochasticity, so $M\cdot v=v$). So, any Markov matrix has eigenvalue $1$. Now, a stationary distribution $p_\infty $ satisfies $M\cdot p_\infty =p_\infty $ so $p_\infty $ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. However, $p_\infty $ should also be a distribution, so should have non-negative entires summing up to $1$. Such a vector does not necessarily have to be a multiply of the eigenvector above (the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ could have dimension greater than $1$).

Comment: This confuses left- and right-eigenvectors. Note that $1$ is an eigenvalue because $v$ is a right-eigenvector and that every stationary distribution $p_\infty$ is a left-eigenvector (or the other way round, depending on your convention).

Comment: So if the eigenvalue of 1 repeats, I may be stuck with the full calculation?